# Recursion-like behaviour in a Promise chain

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, es6-promise

I am currently struggling with the implementation of a recursion to a specific Promiseblock.

I abstracted my code down to this to provide an example:

```
function x(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    return resolve(2)
  })
}

var testvar = 0

x()
.then(result => {
    // simulating mongodb request which returns another promise
    return new Promise(resolve => {resolve()})
})
.then(result => { // BLOCK START
    // simulating another operation
  testvar += 1
  return new Promise(resolve => {resolve()})
})
.then(result => {
    // some other operations

  if(testvar < 2){
   // RERUN PROMISE FROM BLOCK START
   console.log("pls recurse")
  }else{
    // some other operation
    return new Promise(resolve => {resolve()})
  }
  // BLOCK END
})
.then(result => {
    // continue
  console.log("foo")
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))



// classic approach

function y(){
    // something
    // Operation 1
    // Operation 2
  if(x != 1 ){
    y() // recurse
  }else{
    // continue
  }
}
```

Now what I want this code to do is to run the Promisechain one after the other till the last one (the one which logs "foo"). UNLESS testvar is smaller than 2, then I want the Function from "// BLOCK START" to be executed again until testvar is greater or equal 2.

I am relying on this Promisebased build because I am making some asynchronous function calls to a helper library and a mongodb which returns promises.

Code can also be tested in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mhso3us/4/)

If something is unclear feel free to ask - I will gladly try to precise my question.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: For recursion, you always need a `function`. I don't see any in the promise chain part of your code.

Comment: I know I couldn't get my head around how I should implement it. I guess I was blind due to my focus on the Promises :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a big difference to a normal recursive function. You would move your code into a `runBlock` function, and in your `if` condition you either call the `return runBlock(result);` again or your return your resolved Promise:

```
function x() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve(2)
  })
}

var testvar = 0

function runBlock(result) {

  testvar += 1
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve()
    })
    .then(result => {
      // some other operations

      if (testvar < 2) {
        console.log('testvar < 2');
        // RERUN PROMISE FROM BLOCK START
        return runBlock(result);
      } else {
        console.log('testvar >= 2');
        // some other operation
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve()
        })
      }
      // BLOCK END
    })
}


x()
  .then(result => {
    // simulating mongodb request which returns another promise
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve()
    })
  })
  .then(runBlock)
  .then(result => {
    // continue
    console.log("foo")
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))


function a(a) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(a)
  })
}

// classic approach

function y() {
  // something
  // Operation 1
  // Operation 2
  if (x != 1) {
    y() // recurse
  } else {
    // continue
  }
}
```

Comment: It's very nice but i see a lot of unnecessary promisifying within the `then` block. Why don't you just return the result since `then` returns a promise anyways.

Comment: @Redu I belive the OP just created some placeholders for the real code to illustrate the Problem, so I didn't change them and only coverted the code into a recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simplified version of @t.niese's recursion within promises. It's doable as follows;

```js
var      pr = Promise.resolve(1),
fulFillment = v =>  Promise.resolve(v*=2)
                           .then(v => v > 100 ? "foo" : (console.log(v), fulFillment(v)));

pr.then(fulFillment)
  .then(v => console.log(v))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```